# Why would my computer suddenly refuse to open one particular website?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser

I've had this happen once before recently on a different site, and I don't know what I did to fix it.

Now my computer will not open any page on `stackoverflow.com`. When I try, I get the error message:

> Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host

or

> The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while
>   the page was loading. The site could be temporarily unavailable or too
>   busy. Try again in a few moments.

This is odd, especially because it doesn't seem to matter what browser I'm using. I'll encounter the error in Firefox, for instance, but then the same thing occurs a few minutes later in Safari. Or Chrome.

Chrome says:

> The connection to stackoverflow.com was interrupted

and at the bottom of the dialog:

> Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

When I try to access the site from a different computer, no problem.

I've removed all cookies that I can identify as coming from `stackoverflow.com` and quit and re-started the browser. No difference.

Ideas?

Comment: I should add that I'm using a MacOS computer with Lion.

Comment: What if you use a different computer on your network?  Does power cycling your router fix it?

Comment: Could you edit your original question to specify : your OS, what equipment is between your computer and your Internet access, if you use a proxy, if you use any application firewall?

Comment: On your Mac, create a new (non admin) account and check if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an entry in your /etc/hosts file preventing you from connecting to stack overflow or you could have a firewall that is preventing you from connecting to stack overflow. You could try

```
sudo ipfw list
```

this will print any blocks on the computer

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the site is being blocked by some antimalware software, which could be a mistake by a heuristic, a malfunction, or a timeout.  I've seen this problem intermittently on apparently random sites with Sophos Home Edition, and it's been [reported in their forums](http://openforum.sophos.com/t5/Sophos-Anti-Virus-for-Mac-Home/Allowed-Websites/td-p/19391).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble - reddit and some other sites suddenly became inaccessible.

The provider confirmed there was no blocking business at their end. The solution was to change the DNS server settings to Google's public DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. I tried this because there were some odd looking IP's in the service provider's DNS settings. See if it works - update the DNS servers in your settings: system preferences -> Network -> Advanced (after selecting the active network connection) -> DNS tab -> add the two aforementioned IP's for your DNS servers.

Comment: As an aside: did you investigate those odd-looking IP addresses? It might indicate that some malware is trying to route your network to their liking.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I did! Those were standard IP's for the service provider's DNS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be related to:

- Firewall rules

  If you've got a firewall installed (such as [*LittleSnitch*](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)), double check its configuration and delete any rules which may blocking the outgoing connections.

  If you're using some corporate network, it could be blocked by the network administrator.
- Domain Name Servers (DNS) issues

  Double check that you've got the right DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and you don't have any hardcoded hostnames in your `/etc/hosts`.

  Run `stackoverflow.com` to see if the hostname is translated into the proper IP address.
- Proxy

  Make sure you don't use any reverse proxies and you've disabled it in your configuration.
- VPN

  If you're connecting using VPN, try connecting directly.

How to debug? To check for the outgoing traffic, you can use `tcpdump` command-line tool.

Related posts:

- [Why can't I browse the internet with Safari, but Chrome is working?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34824/22781)
- [Safari does not load any site but there is Internet connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/131505/22781)
- [Unable to connect to websites which don't start with www](https://superuser.com/q/1187329/87805)